# Влияет ли негативно запуск телефона через Android Studio

Tags: android

Я начал заниматься Android разработкой и постоянно приходится собирать проект и запускать apk на своем телефоне, даже при маленьких изменениях приходится перезапускать, влияет ли это негативно на мой телефон, в эмуляторе не работаю т.к комп виснет.

Comment: Влияет не больше, чем его обычное использование. В любом случае, вы его смените раньше, чем он выработает какой-то ресурс. Из эмуляторов - можете попробовать популярный Genymotion

Comment: У меня батарея быстрее садится садится на Xiaomi. На Самсунге тоже быстрее умерла чем ожидалось от обычного использования. У бесплатного Генимоушн  довольно хороший функционал и скорость. Но я меньше стал пользоваться, так как на телефоне быстрее запускается.